# Cannot Read XML child in array

Tags: php, json, xml

I am trying to read this xml content http://auroserver.com/sandbox/xml.xml as arrays using PHP

i've read some QA here but still cannot implement how to read these file completely.

I am using this code:

```
$url            = 'http://auroserver.com/sandbox/xml.xml';
$fileContents   = file_get_contents($url);
$fileContents   = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
$fileContents   = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
$Xml            = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
$xml_array      = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $Xml), 1)));
var_dump($xml_array);
```

using above code, it only return:

```
array(3) {
  ["Status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["Message"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Content"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

how to render all xml child values? for this things i need to read these values in the xml file:

```
<CardNo>6048180000002031</CardNo>
<Status>true</Status>
<Ebalance>92900</Ebalance>
<RewardPoint>6900</RewardPoint>
```

thank you

Comment: Can you need the output in XML format ?

Comment: i am more familiar with array instead of XML format

Comment: Okay, But o/p comes in array format, do you need in xml format

Comment: i have no idea, as long i can read all values i want

Comment: $json_url = "http://auroserver.com/sandbox/xml.xml";
        $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
        $data = json_decode($json, TRUE); //To convert object to array format.
pls check this, i am not sure

Comment: i use var_dump($data); it return NULL

Comment: Are you check this code ? it's work or not ?
*json_decode($json, TRUE); //To convert object to array format

Comment: yes, I've check your code. I've use that code before anyway. it returns NULL

Comment: i am also use the same code it's work fine, i thing problem from api
run url in browser it display any output

Comment: what is your output anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you do not have any specific reason to do so, there is no need to convert the XML into an array. If your goal is just to grab the values mentioned, you could use an [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) query to get them directly from the XML:

```
$url            = 'http://auroserver.com/sandbox/xml.xml';
$fileContents   = trim(file_get_contents($url));

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($fileContents);
$table = $xml->xpath('//NewDataSet/Table')[0]; # 0 = first item
echo "CardNo:      " . $table->CardNo, PHP_EOL;
echo "Status:      " . $table->Status, PHP_EOL;
echo "Ebalance:    " . $table->Ebalance, PHP_EOL;
echo "RewardPoint: " . $table->RewardPoint, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
CardNo:      6048180000002031
Status:      true
Ebalance:    92900
RewardPoint: 6900
```

Comment: Thank you..i'll used your solution

Comment: for getting output in array, just replace all echo things with this code: foreach ($table as $y => $z) {
 echo $y . " = " . $z ."<br/>";
}